# Unable to Read CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I am using simple code to read csv file

```
import pandas as pd
url = '/content/tough_dataset (1).csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Instead of reading the file I am getting an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 29: unexpected end of data
```

I am using Google Collab for this implementation

Comment: It looks like that CSV is not in UTF-8 format. Do you know the encoding?

Comment: try this to get the encoding 'with open('my_test.csv') as f:
    print(f)' and then read your csv with that coding, example like `df= pd.read_csv('my_test.csv', encoding ='iso8859_2')` . for python encoding refer [Python Standard Encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: This is the dataset which I am trying to import https://github.com/SomDutta2000/ProtonAutoML/blob/main/tough_dataset.csv

Comment: After performing `with open('my_test.csv') as f: print(f)` got '<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/content/tough_dataset.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>'